# The parameter PASSWORD cannot be provided for users that cannot authenticate in a database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-project

When I log in to azure portal select my SQL Database -> Tools -> QueryEditor and enter:

```
ALTER USER MyUser WITH Password = '**********'
```

I get the error:

> Failed to execute query. Error: The parameter PASSWORD cannot be
>   provided for users that cannot authenticate in a database.

I've created the user in Visual Studio Database Project in MyUser.sql (Build Action=Build):

```
CREATE USER [My_User] WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo];
```

Why I'm getting the message?

Is it possible to create the User in Database Project so that I will specify the password later (not is source code)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your user is not a contained database user that can be authenticated by database. This is because you did not create it with syntax

```
CREATE USER user_name WITH PASSWORD = 'strong_password';
```

What you've created is a "traditional" user without login, in "traditional" model `user` cannot have a password, only the corresponding `login` can. But your user has no corresponding login as it was created `without login`, so you cannot change a password at all.

Here you can find more detailes about contained database urers: [Contained Database Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable)

Comment: I use users without login for testing purpose. You can create such a user in your database, give him some premissions and test your code executed by this test user: execute as user='myTESTuser'...some code...revert.

Comment: So no solution?

Comment: So you should first create login and then a user, and change a password of login, or make your database contained and create a user with password.